Flux somehow tries to bootstrap on random cluster
I use terraform to set up a cluster and install fluxcd on it.
The cluster is set up correctly (i see both in azure portal).
In the bootstrap step however, i get an error showing that flux tries to access a cluster that i do not know and do not have access to (can't find it in azure portal).
 Error: Bootstrap run error
│ 
│   with module.flux.flux_bootstrap_git.this,
│   on modules/flux/main.tf line 58, in resource "flux_bootstrap_git" "this":
│   58: resource "flux_bootstrap_git" "this" {
│ 
│ CustomResourceDefinition/alerts.notification.toolkit.fluxcd.io dry-run failed: Get
│ "https://****-*****.westeurope.azmk8s.io:443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp: lookup
│ ****-*****.westeurope.azmk8s.io on ***.***.***.53:53: no such host

Here is how i setup/install flux on the cluster:
provider "flux" {
  kubernetes = {
    config_path = "~/.kube/config"
  }
  git = {
    author_email = "*******@*******.com"
    url = "https://dev.azure.com/*******/*******/_git/flux"
    http = {
      username = "*******@*******.com"
      password = "*******"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_extension" "flux" {
  name           = "flux"
  cluster_id     = var.aks_cluster_id
  extension_type = "microsoft.flux"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_flux_configuration" "k8s_flux" {
  name       = "flux-system"
  cluster_id = var.aks_cluster_id
  namespace  = "flux-system"

  git_repository {
    url             = "https://*******@dev.azure.com/*******/*******/_git/flux"
    reference_type  = "branch"
    reference_value = "main"
  }

  kustomizations {
    name                      = "kustomization"
    path                      = "./clusters/test/00"
    sync_interval_in_seconds  = 120
    retry_interval_in_seconds = 120
  }

  scope = "cluster"

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_extension.flux
  ]
}

resource "flux_bootstrap_git" "this" {
  path = "clusters/test/"
  components = [
    "source-controller",
    "kustomize-controller",
    "helm-controller",
    "notification-controller"
  ]
  log_level = "debug"
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_extension.flux
  ]
}


Here is how i export the k8s config to use in the flux setup:
resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  depends_on   = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks]
  filename     = "~/.kube/config"
  content      = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config_raw
}

Here is how i set up the aks cluster: https://pastebin.com/aC7E7n9W

You don't need these blocks:
provider "flux" {
...
}

and
resource "flux_bootstrap_git" "this" {
...
}

Azure does it for you with azurerm_kubernetes_flux_configuration
btw check your var.aks_cluster_id

Thanks! That was indeed the Problem. I used both possible ways to set it up because i was misleaded a blog post.
What do you meand with checking my cluster id?
